# interpolating values from a dataframe based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, eval, interpolation

Assuming I have a the following problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xp = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]

np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['x0', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3'])

df
      x0     y1     y2     y3
0 0.5434 0.2784 0.4245 0.8448
1 0.0047 0.1216 0.6707 0.8259
2 0.1367 0.5751 0.8913 0.2092
3 0.1853 0.1084 0.2197 0.9786
4 0.8117 0.1719 0.8162 0.2741
5 0.4317 0.9400 0.8176 0.3361
6 0.1754 0.3728 0.0057 0.2524
7 0.7957 0.0153 0.5988 0.6038
8 0.1051 0.3819 0.0365 0.8904
9 0.9809 0.0599 0.8905 0.5769
```

I would like to interpolate a column named `interp`. The value x-coordinate to be interpolated is contained in column `x0`, the x-coordinate of the data points would be `xp`, and the y-coordinates of the data points would be contained in `y1`, `y2` and `y3`.

So far, I came up with the following:

```
df['interp'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.interp(x.x0, xp, [x.y1, x.y2, x.y3]), axis=1)

df
      x0     y1     y2     y3  interp
0 0.5434 0.2784 0.4245 0.8448  0.4610
1 0.0047 0.1216 0.6707 0.8259  0.1268
2 0.1367 0.5751 0.8913 0.2092  0.6616
3 0.1853 0.1084 0.2197 0.9786  0.1496
4 0.8117 0.1719 0.8162 0.2741  0.4783
5 0.4317 0.9400 0.8176 0.3361  0.8344
6 0.1754 0.3728 0.0057 0.2524  0.2440
7 0.7957 0.0153 0.5988 0.6038  0.6018
8 0.1051 0.3819 0.0365 0.8904  0.3093
9 0.9809 0.0599 0.8905 0.5769  0.5889
```

However, the dataframe on which this calculation will be performed contains more than a million lines, so I'd like to privilege a faster method than `apply`. Any ideas?

`np.interp` only seems to take 1-D arrays, and this is the reason I went with `apply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good solution for making this faster is [`pandas.DataFrame.eval()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#expression-evaluation-via-eval-experimental):

**TL;DR**

```
Seconds per number of rows
Rows:     100   1000  10000    1E5    1E6    1E7
apply:  0.076  0.734  7.812
eval:   0.056  0.053  0.058  0.087  0.338  2.887
```

As can be seen from these timings, `eval()` has a lot of setup overhead, and up to 10,000 rows basically takes the same time. But it is two orders of magnitude faster than the apply, and thus it certainly worth the overhead for large data sets.

**What is it?**

From the ([DOCS](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval))

```
pandas.eval(expr, parser='pandas', engine=None, truediv=True, 
            local_dict=None, global_dict=None, resolvers=(),
            level=0, target=None, inplace=None)
```

> Evaluate a Python expression as a string using various backends.
>
> The following arithmetic operations are supported: +, -, *, /, ** , %, // (python engine only) along with the following boolean operations: | (or), & (and), and ~ (not). Additionally, the 'pandas' parser allows the use of and, or, and not with the same semantics as the corresponding bitwise operators. Series and DataFrame objects are supported and behave as they would with plain ol’ Python evaluation.

**Tricks performed for this Question:**

The code below exploits the fact that the interpolation is always only in two segments.  It actually calculates the interpolant for both segments, and then discards the unused segment via a multiply by a bool test (ie, 0, 1)

The actual expression passed to eval is:

```
((y2-y1) / 0.5 * (x0-0.0) + y1) * (x0 < 0.5)+((y3-y2) / 0.5 * (x0-0.5) + y2) * (x0 >= 0.5)
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xp = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]

np.random.seed(100)

def method1():
    df['interp'] = df.apply(
        lambda x: np.interp(x.x0, xp, [x.y1, x.y2, x.y3]), axis=1)

def method2():
    exp = '((y%d-y%d) / %s * (x0-%s) + y%d) * (x0 %s 0.5)'
    exp_1 = exp % (2, 1, xp[1] - xp[0], xp[0], 1, '<')
    exp_2 = exp % (3, 2, xp[2] - xp[1], xp[1], 2, '>=')

    df['interp2'] = df.eval(exp_1 + '+' + exp_2)

from timeit import timeit

def runit(stmt):
    print("%s: %.3f" % (
        stmt, timeit(stmt + '()', number=10,
                     setup='from __main__ import ' + stmt)))

def runit_size(size):
    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.rand(size, 4), columns=['x0', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3'])

    print('Rows: %d' % size)
    if size <= 10000:
        runit('method1')
    runit('method2')

for i in (100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000):
    runit_size(i)

print(df.head())
```

**Results:**

```
         x0        y1        y2        y3    interp   interp2
0  0.060670  0.949837  0.608659  0.672003  0.908439  0.908439
1  0.462774  0.704273  0.181067  0.647582  0.220021  0.220021
2  0.568109  0.954138  0.796690  0.585310  0.767897  0.767897
3  0.455355  0.738452  0.812236  0.927291  0.805648  0.805648
4  0.826376  0.029957  0.772803  0.521777  0.608946  0.608946
```

Comment: @StevenG, `eval()` is screaming fast, if you can squeeze you calc into its model.  :-)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I will try to adapt my problem to your answer. The issue is that I was trying to provide a simplified problem, and my interpolation takes more columns at the end. I will try to look at what I could do without pandas (numpy only). However, thank you for your answer, it is probably the best insight using pandas!

Comment: Since this is 100x faster than apply, you can scale this solution to 5 or ten segments pretty easily, and it will still be faster by quite a lot.  Also, if you can apriori limit a particular set of rows to a range of possibilities, then this will still be quite a bit faster.  Good Luck to you.

Comment: I just tested your answer on a dafaframe with more columns and it works perfectly!