# Linear interpolation of two 2D arrays

Tags: numpy, scipy, interpolation, array-broadcasting

In a previous question ([fastest way to use numpy.interp on a 2-D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772218/fastest-way-to-use-numpy-interp-on-a-2-d-array)) someone asked for the fastest way to implement the following:

```
np.array([np.interp(X[i], x, Y[i]) for i in range(len(X))])
```

assume `X` and `Y` are matrices with many rows so the for loop is costly. There is a nice solution in this case that avoids the for loop (see linked answer above).

---

I am faced with a very similar problem, but I am unclear on whether the for loop can be avoided in this case:

```
np.array([np.interp(x, X[i], Y[i]) for i in range(len(X))])
```

In other words, I want to use linear interpolation to upsample a large number of signals stored in the rows of two matrices `X` and `Y`.
I was hoping to find a function in numpy or scipy (scipy.interpolate.interp1d) that supported this operation via broadcasting semantics but I so far can't seem to find one.

*Other points:*

- If it helps, the rows `X[i]` and `x` are pre-sorted in my application. Also, in my case `len(x)` is quite a bit larger than `len(X[i])`.
- The function [`scipy.signal.resample`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html) almost does what I want, but it doesn't use linear interpolation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a vectorized approach that directly implements linear interpolation. First, for each x value and each i, j compute the weight `w` expressing how much of the interval (X[i, j],  X[i, j+1]) is to the left of x.

- If the entire interval is to the left of x, the weight of that interval is 1.
- If none of the subinterval is to the left, the weight is 0
- Otherwise, the weight is a number between 0 and 1, expressing the proportion of that interval to the left of x.

Then the value of PL interpolant is computed as Y[i, 0] + sum of differences dY[i, j] multiplied by the corresponding weight. The logic is to follow by how much the interpolant changes from interval to interval. The differences `dY = np.diff(Y, axis=1)` show how much it changes over the entire interval. Multiplication by the weight prorates that change accordingly.

#### Setup, with some small data arrays

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[0, 2, 5, 6, 9], [1, 3, 4, 7, 8]])
Y = np.array([[3, 5, 2, 4, 1], [8, 6, 9, 5, 4]])
x = np.linspace(1, 8, 20)
```

#### The computation

```
dX = np.diff(X, axis=1)
dY = np.diff(Y, axis=1)
w = np.clip((x - X[:, :-1, None])/dX[:, :, None], 0, 1)
y = Y[:, [0]] + np.sum(w*dY[:, :, None], axis=1)
```

#### Demonstration

This is only to show that the interpolation is correct. Blue points: original data, red ones are computed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y[0], 'ro')
plt.plot(X[0], Y[0], 'bo')
plt.plot(x, y[1], 'rd')
plt.plot(X[1], Y[1], 'bd')
plt.show()
```

[image: PL interpolants]

Comment: This assumes all elements of (X,Y) have the same length though :\