# numpy interpolation with array-valued `yp`

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to interpolate array-valued data, i.e., the x-values are one-dimensional, but the y-values are (NumPy) arrays. The following doesn't work:

```py
import numpy as np

xp = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0])
yp = np.array(
    [
        [-1.1, 2.4, 5.1, 5.6],
        [7.1, -2.1, 9.1, 31.0],
        [1.1, 13.4, -5.2, 5.6],
    ]
)

np.interp(0.4, xp, yp)
```

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Any hints?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fastest way to use numpy.interp on a 2-D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772218/fastest-way-to-use-numpy-interp-on-a-2-d-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
def interp(x, xp, fp, left=None, right=None, period=None):
    """
    One-dimensional linear interpolation for monotonically increasing sample points.

    Returns the one-dimensional piecewise linear interpolant to a function
    with given discrete data points (`xp`, `fp`), evaluated at `x`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array_like
        The x-coordinates at which to evaluate the interpolated values.

    xp : 1-D sequence of floats
        The x-coordinates of the data points, must be increasing if argument
        `period` is not specified. Otherwise, `xp` is internally sorted after
        normalizing the periodic boundaries with ``xp = xp % period``.

    fp : 1-D sequence of float or complex
        The y-coordinates of the data points, same length as `xp`.
```

The `fp` (`yp`) parameter should be a 1-D array and it should have the same length as `xp`. For example, calling `interp` on every sublist of transposed `yp` will work

```
for lst in yp.T:
    print(np.interp(0.4, xp, lst))
```

Output:

```
2.1799999999999997
0.5999999999999999
6.699999999999999
15.76
```

Answer (score 0):

according to numpy documentation

> numpy.interp
>
> Returns the one-dimensional piecewise linear interpolant to a function
> with given discrete data points (xp, fp), evaluated at x.
>
> Parameters: xarray_like The x-coordinates at which to evaluate the
> interpolated values.
>
> xp1-D sequence of floats The x-coordinates of the data points, must be
> increasing if argument period is not specified. Otherwise, xp is
> internally sorted after normalizing the periodic boundaries with xp =
> xp % period.
>
> fp1-D sequence of float or complex The y-coordinates of the data
> points, same length as xp.

But in your code yp, is 2D array.

You can do it by doing the interpolation for each set of your array using a for loop.

```
yp = np.array([np.interp(x, xp, yp[0:, i]) for i in range(yp.shape[1])])
print(yp)
[ 2.18  0.6   6.7  15.76]
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `np.interp` takes a 1D `yp` array but you are providing a 2D array. I'll just throw out another option using `np.apply_along_axis`.

```py
res = np.apply_along_axis(lambda _yp: np.interp(0.4, xp, _yp), 0, yp)
print(res)  # [ 2.18  0.6   6.7  15.76]
```

And to comment on the list comprehension approaches, you can use the transpose of the array to just loop through the data rather than using `range` and indexing, which will be *very slightly* faster as you increase the amount of data.

```py
res = [np.interp(0.4, xp, _yp) for _yp in yp.T]
```