linearly interpolate 1D array against n dimensional arrays over axis in parallel
Is there any way to interpolate an 1D array against two n-dimensional arrays along certain axis?
In particular, I have x and y arrays with shapes (6, 2, 10). I also have an x_in array with shape(10, ) that I would like to interpolate along first axis. Is there any elegant way to achieve this with any interpolation function in numpy or scipy?
In the following code, T has shape (2,), B has shape (10, ) and x_in has shape (10, ), as well. I would like to obtain an array with shape (2, 10) as below but avoid for loop.
def foo(T, B, x_in):
    len_T = len(T)
    len_x_in = len(x_in)
    x = np.ones((6, len_T, len_x_in))
    x[0, :, :] = 0
    x[1, :, :] = 0.3 - 0.1*T[:, np.newaxis]
    x[2, :, :] = 0.35 - 0.1*T[:, np.newaxis]
    x[3, :, :] = 0.8 - 0.2*T[:, np.newaxis]
    x[4, :, :] = 0.9 - 0.2*T[:, np.newaxis]
    x[5, :, :] = 1.0

    y = np.ones((6, len_T, len_x_in))
    y[0, :, :] = -0.25*T[:, np.newaxis]*(1 + B)
    y[1, :, :] = -1
    y[2, :, :] = 1
    y[3, :, :] = 1
    y[4, :, :] = -1
    y[5, :, :] = -1
    
    out = np.ones((len_T, len_x_in))
    for i in range(len_T):
        for j in range(len_x_in):
            out[i, j] = np.interp([x_in[j]], x[:, i, j], y[:, i, j])
    return out    

Is there any function to vectorise/parallelise the above interpolation?

Regarding the target array size, the overhead of Numpy calls should be really huge so vectorization is the way to go indeed. Numba should help to get much better performance here (IDK if this is possible in Numpy). Regarding parallelism, there is a significant overhead for spawning and joining threads and I expect it to be much bigger than the actual computation once vectorized properly. Thus, parallelization is useless here.

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772218/fastest-way-to-use-numpy-interp-on-a-2-d-array

In the real problem, what's the approximste size of the arrays? Sometimes iterating on one of the smaller dimensions can be relatively fast.  For what it does interp is already pretty good.

The first dimension won't have a big size (approx 4 to 6). However, the second can have size over one million (it represents x coordinates of nodes comprising a mesh). The interpolation is to be called multiple times during the solution. This is the reason why I am trying to optimise this.
