# Problems scraping URLs and nested CSV to combine with python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

My project requires me to scrape information from a website in several steps, with each step adding new pages and variables to scrape in the steps that follow. I am using Python for this...learned very basic aspects only 3 months ago, still very new at it.

The sequence for scraping is as follows:

Step 0: 
CSV1 file of top-category URLs to scrape (url_1), about 20 urls total

-->

Step 1: 
Takes scrape1.py, which uses Selenium Firefox Webdriver to load each (url_1) link in CSV1 to make CSV2 containing the following mid-category variables in columns: (variable1), (variable2), (variable3), (variable4), (variable5), (url_2)...each loading of (url_1) produces 12-24 new rows with a unique (url_2) link, so about 400+ rows total

-->

Step 2: 
Uses scrape2.py and Beautiful Soup to load each (url_2) link in CSV2 and make CSV3 containing the following end-category variables in columns: (variable_A), (variable_a), (url_a), (variable_B), (variable_b), (url_B), (url_b). Each (url_2) link produces 20+ of each variable (A, a, B, b) and url (a, B, b), so output would be well over 10,000 rows (currently have only run this on a smaller version of CSV2 that has only 5 rows of url_2)

-->

Step 3:

Combine all the variables into one CSV4 file.

The problem I am running into is in Step 3. I was able to create CSV1, CSV2, and (a truncated) CSV3. I was able to make scrape1.py and scrape2.py and successfully collect the variables and URLs. But I *cannot* figure out how to get all the variables into one CSV file. Especially because each stage exponentially increases the number of variables that follow, such that one row of (url_1) in CSV1 will produce 200-400+ rows of variables in CSV3. I need to "carry over" the variables from one CSV file to the next, but the new file will have to have the carry over variables in it many times for each new iteration of rows, not just once, so just adding them as a new column won't work.

Final output should be:

CSV1: (url_1) [x20]

CSV2: for each (url_1), around 22 rows of:
(variable1), (variable2), (variable3), (variable4), (variable5), (url_2)

CSV3: for each (url_2), around 30 rows of:
(variable_A), (variable_a), (url_a), (variable_B), (variable_b), (url_B), (url_b)

CSV4: each row from CSV3 replicated with previous variables, such that each row has:
(url_1), (variable1), (variable2), (variable3), (variable4), (variable5), (url_2),(variable_A), (variable_a), (url_a), (variable_B), (variable_b), (url_B), (url_b)

Someone suggested I try Pandas, but I wasn't able to figure out how to implement that using just what I read of others' projects.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @StephenRauch thanks for your reply...I did read both those resources before posting and attempted to craft my question following those guidelines. Your comment suggests I didn't do as good of a job as I hoped, so I edited to (hopefully) add some clarity.

Comment: Here are a couple of questions I have answered recently that show a bit of what folks here would like to see to make the question more answerable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810094/pandas-apply-with-and-without-lambda/43810923#43810923 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765796/interpolating-values-from-a-dataframe-based-on-a-column-value/43770002#43770002. And in constructing an MCVE concentrate on the structure not so much the size.  Although describing the size is important.  But your best results will come with very concrete and reproducible MCVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this finally. Appreciate the help from other users. Solution was not to merge CSVs, but to carry some variables over to the new ones. I figure I'd post the solution in case someone else finds it useful later.

CSV1, with each variable in separate rows:

```
    url_1_00.html
    url_1_01.html
    url_1_02.html
```

(full CSV1 contains ~50 URLs)

Each URL is to a page with a (complicated) list of needed information, which is 10-30 items long and one of those items is the second URL. I need to scrape each item in each list, from each of the 50 URLs, into a new CSV.

Scrape1.py: *(Note: I have made this code generic; in reality the scraper variables required much more navigation and some clicks and drop downs, which is why I used Selenium, specifically).*

```
    ### HEADER: IMPORTS AND DEFINITIONS ###

    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    import datetime
    import time
    import csv

    driver=webdriver.Firefox()

    raw_data_file = open("CSV1.csv", 'rU')
    csv_data_file = csv.reader(raw_data_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    csv_data_file.next()

    ###DEFINE FUNCTIONS HERE###

    def scraper():
            var_1 = driver.find_element_by_id('var_1_id').text
            var_2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.list_item.odd')
            lotta_varslist = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.list_item.odd')
            for each in lotta_varslist:
                    var_3 = each.find_element_by_class_name('classwhut')
                    var_4 = each.find_element_by_tag_name('strong')
                    var_5 = each.find_element_by_id('id_whut')
                    url_2 = each.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute("href")
                    summary=[url_1, var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, url_2]
                    #NOTICE url_1 is in this summary even though it's origin is 
                    #in CSV1, not scraped from the page like all the other 
                    #variables defined in this function...it can carry over
                    scrapetehvars.append(summary)

    def write_to_csv():
            with open('CSV2.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            writer.writerow(["url_1", "var_1", "var_2", "var_3", "var_4", "var_5", "url_2"]) 
            #NOTICE url_1 is here as well ^^^
            writer.writerows(scrapetehvars)

    ###BEGIN ACTUAL PROGRAM###

    scrapetehvars=[]

    for each in csv_data_file:
            url_1=each[0] 
            #NOTICE this is where url_1 is actually 
            #defined, pulled from CSV1 using the 
            #csv_data_file variable defined in the Header
            driver.get(url_1)
            scraper()
            write_to_csv()
            time.sleep(1)

    print "ALL DONE!"

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

A couple of notes here:
CSV1 contains all the initial URLs, defined as url_1.

That produced CSV2, which had the next set of URLs I needed to scrape in it. CSV2 was 800+ rows long (so the ~50 URLs that were url_1 produced 800+ URLs that were url_2)

Example of CSV2, with each set of variables in different rows, variables comma separated:

```
    url_1_00, var_1_00, var_2_00, var_3_00, var_4_00, var_5_00, url_2_00.html  
    url_1_00, var_1_01, var_2_01, var_3_01, var_4_01, var_5_01, url_2_01.html  
    url_1_00, var_1_02, var_2_02, var_3_02, var_4_02, var_5_02, url_2_02.html  
    url_1_00, var_1_03, var_2_03, var_3_03, var_4_03, var_5_03, url_2_03.html  
    url_1_00, var_1_04, var_2_04, var_3_04, var_4_04, var_5_04, url_2_04.html
```

(full CSV2 contains ~800 rows of above variable-url sets)

Now I need to scrape each url_2 and for another list of (complicated) variables. Each list on the url_2 page contains 30-100 items with ~4 variable attributes, and I need each item scraped to its own row with its variable attributes added, while keeping the information from the previous scrape (url_1, var_1, var_2...through url_2).

The result was the following:

Scrape2.py: *(Note: I have made this code generic; this part didn't require clicks so I used BeautifulSoup).*

```
    ### HEADER: IMPORTS AND DEFINITIONS ###

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time 
    import csv, codecs, cStringIO

    raw_data_file = open("CSV2.csv", 'rU')
    csv_data_file = csv.reader(raw_data_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    csv_data_file.next()

    ###DEFINE FUNCTIONS HERE###

    def scrapertron():
            moarvarslist=soup.find_all('tr')
            for each in moarvarslist:
                    var_a = None
                    try: 
                            var_a = each.find('td', class_="classwhut")
                    except: pass
                    url_a = None
                    try: 
                            url_a = each.find('a').get('href')
                    except: pass
                    var_b = None
                    try: 
                            var_b = each.find('tr', class_="heyyyanotherone")
                    except: pass
                    url_b = None
                    try: 
                            url_b = each.find('a').get('href')
                    except: pass
                    newsummary=[url_1, var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, url_2, var_a, url_a, var_b, var_b]
                    # NOTICE as in the previous scrape, this carries over
                    # variables that aren't in the scrape from CSV2, namely
                    # url_1, var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, and url_2
                    scrapeallvars.append(summary)

    def write_to_csv():
            with open('CSV3.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            writer.writerow(["url_1", "var_1", "var_2", "var_3", "var_4", "var_5", "url_2", "var_a", "url_a", "var_b", "var_b"])
            # NOTICE again, the carry over variables from CSV2 here ^^^
            writer.writerows(scrapeallvars)

    ###BEGIN ACTUAL PROGRAM###

    scrapeallvars=[]

    for each in csv_data_file:
            url_1=each[0]
            var_1=each[1]
            var_2=each[2]
            var_3=each[3]
            var_4=each[4]
            var_5=each[5]
            url_2=each[6]
            # The variables from CSV2 are actually defined here, after
            # they are pulled using csv_data_file

            response = requests.get(url_2)  
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

            scrapertron()
            write_to_csv()
            time.sleep(3)

    print "ALL DONE!"
```

This produces all the needed variables in the final file, CSV3. There is no longer any need for CSV4. All the url_2 URLs produce 30-100 new variable items in the list, which results in 120,000+ rows in the final file. This scrape takes a lot longer, because it's iterating through 800+ rows of url_2. For me, this took about an hour, though if I hadn't used time.sleep() it could have taken 15-20 minutes instead, but I didn't want to overwhelm the site(s) I was scraping from.

Example of CSV3 output, with each set of variables in different rows, variables comma separated:

```
    url_1_00, var_1_00, var_2_00, var_3_00, var_4_00, var_5_00, url_2_00, var_a_000, url_a_000, var_b_000, url_b_000  
    url_1_00, var_1_00, var_2_00, var_3_00, var_4_00, var_5_00, url_2_00, var_a_001, url_a_001, var_b_001, url_b_001  
    url_1_00, var_1_00, var_2_00, var_3_00, var_4_00, var_5_00, url_2_00, var_a_002, url_a_002, var_b_002, url_b_002  
    url_1_00, var_1_00, var_2_00, var_3_00, var_4_00, var_5_00, url_2_00, var_a_003, url_a_003, var_b_003, url_b_003
```

Know this is long, but maybe someone somewhere sometime needs it!

Answer (score 1):

With CSVs with columns:

- CSV1

  - **url_1**
- CSV2

  - **url_1**
  - variable1
  - **url_2**
- CSV3

  - **url_2**
  - variable_A

If you want to merge these CSVs, just use [pandas.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

*pandas.merge(CSV1, CSV2)* will join CSV1 and CSV2 using their common columns(in the example, column **url_1**).

Look at the example [here](https://gist.github.com/abevieiramota/04eb57884f54688c902004f8e88d63ea).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The tricky part of this was going to be that it wasn't quite a merge; each CSV list generated a much larger list each time, and I wanted some variables to carry over. I managed to do this using a different technique, but what you sent me helped figure it out!